# Performance troubles with Motorola Moto X Force (Android 7.0)

Tags: 7.0-nougat, performance, cpu

Since quite some time I am having some peculiar performance problems on my Motorola Moto X Force. Sometimes any interaction (like just opening Chrome for example) takes incredibly long until it responds. This also happens after clearing all apps in the task switcher and it can also happen pretty soon after rebooting the phone.

Imho a phone with a 4x 2.00GHz Cortex-A57 + 4x 1.50GHz Cortex-A53 (Qualcomm MSM8994 Snapdragon 810, 64bit) and 3 GiB RAM should not have such problems.

Thinking some app might hog the CPU in the background (though I do not have any battery problems - it can go for over 48 hours without charging) I installed some system monitoring apps in order to get to the bottom of this.

One app, [System Monitor Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.systemmonitor.lite) has the ability to log in the background, when enabled. I wanted to check if I can correlate CPU or RAM usage with the periods where the phone runs slow.

*However* once the background logging of that app is active, the phone immediately runs noticeably smoother! And it runs smooth as long as the background logging is active. Once I turn it off, the phone will get slow again after some time.

This makes me think now that this phone (or Android 7.0) has a power management problem. i.e. letting the CPU(s) run in a low performance state, when it should not.

Has anyone else ever experienced something like that or any ideas how to combat this?

Comment: Possibly related: [CPU-Z shows 8 cores, but 4 of them are stopped](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/168407/44325)

Answer (score 0):

> Imho a phone with a 4x 2.00GHz Cortex-A57 + 4x 1.50GHz Cortex-A53 (Qualcomm MSM8994 Snapdragon 810, 64bit) and 3 GiB RAM should not have such problems.

No, it should have such problems. SD810 is known to have bad thermal performance (it is essentially a SD410 when under load because all a57 cores shut down). The only thing you can do is do factory reset and remove all junk from your device or install a custom ROM (or a custom Kernel) which has thermal profile that suites your usage pattern.

(I use a Oneplus 2 with same SD810 btw)

Comment: but it does not happen under load. It's the exact opposite. It is slow when there is no load but smooth when there is at least some constant load in the background. I already did a factory reset and removed all "junk". It happens after a fresh reset too. Can you recommend any custom ROMs that would attempt to fix this problem with the thermal profile (if it is that)?

Comment: @fritzmg Seems like you're out of luck. There only one [LOS 14.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-turbo-2/development/rom-cyanogenmod-14-1-kinzie-t3536148) build and it looks abandoned. You can go the hacky way to root your device and modify your stock OS to get more juice out of it. Install Kernel Adiutor and play with some parameters or try some root app/mod that claims to boost performance.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestions. It's too bad though. However, I got an OTA update recently (stock ROM) - which was just some security update according to the description. So far the phone does seem to run more smooth again. But may be that is just a placebo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same bug but it's mainly disk I/O which drastically slows down (or even freezes) the phone. I've installed [Simple System Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app&hl=fr) and you can check disk I/O (and even test read/write speed), and it's absolutely awful (test file size 200 MB) :

- read speed : 44.45 MB/s
- write speed : **2,91** MB/s

I'll go for a factory reset as my internal storage is more than 75% full but I fear this might be a material issu with the internal storage...